# Select * for mysql prepare statement not listing anything

Tags: mysql, prepare

I'm trying to convert a part of code into prepare statements and can't make work the select statement.

It doesn't throw an error, it just don't list the items. Instead of displaying the results it says there are no entries (double check and there are in db).

Any help is much appreciated.

```
if($_GET[action]=='view-rss')
{
    $count =0;
    $stmt = $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]->prepare("select * from rss where lang=(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION[session_lang]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    while($stmt=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $rss_ids[] = $row['id'];
        $rss_urls[] = $row['url'];
        $rss_titles[] = $row['title'];
        $rss_publishes[] = $row['published'];
        $count= $count +1;
    }
    $smarty->assign("rss_ids", $rss_ids);
    $smarty->assign("rss_urls", $rss_urls);
    $smarty->assign("rss_titles", $rss_titles);
    $smarty->assign("rss_publishes", $rss_publishes);
    $smarty->assign("count", $count);

}
```

Comment: where lang=(?) the parentheses are unnecessary.And I don't think you should close the connection before while loop.

Comment: Also your $query variable is missing,from your snippet at least.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Mihai. I removed the parentheses and tried to put the close in various places after the loop but always getting an error like:
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in admin-rss.php on line 86

Comment: I've also changed $query with: while($stmt=mysqli_fetch_assoc())

Comment: You should have $query=(SELECT something FROM table) and leave this as it was $stmt=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but without luck. What is the proper syntax for the code with your suggestion to assign the select into $query?:

$stmt = $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]->prepare("select * from rss where lang=?");

Comment: Try While( $stmt->fetch())