# Mysql prepare statement does not return anything. No syntax error. Why?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, mariadb, execute, sequelpro

Scenario:
I have a table in a mariaDB. It’s called “pages”. It just has three columns and a few entries for test purposes.

Problem:
I try to create a nice PREPARE statement in SQL. I did not get it working so I ended up with the following ‘simple’ code.

```
PREPARE stmt from 'SELECT * FROM `pages`;';
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It does kind of execute without errors, but it does not show a single row.

What am I missing here?

If you are asking, why I use a prepare statement for such a simple query: It is just for finding the error. The final query will be more complicated with variables etc.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Could be a double of [Select * for mysql prepare statement not listing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399332/select-for-mysql-prepare-statement-not-listing-anything) but maybe not.

**Additional Info**
I run the code as a direct SQL Query in Sequel Pro.

**RIGHT ANSWER**

Joakim Danielson had the right guess.

```
prepare stmt from 'SELECT * FROM `pages`;'; execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This works in Sequel Pro.
**BUT** I totally recommend to not use Sequel Pros command line. Other bugs occurred one after another. Not so in the mysql CLI. Better go with your OS’ command line.

Comment: PREPPARE  ??    or PREPARE

Comment: Why the mysql and sql flags if you're using mariadb? Are you trying to run those commands directly from the command line of mariadb or are you using a programming language like PHP?

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks, but it was just a typo here, not in the real code.

Comment: @Dave I am aiming to run those commands from a node app via the mysql connector https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql
But for testing I run the code directly in Sequel Pro.
The tag....I can dismiss it. Sequel Pro is just telling me MySQL 5.5.5-10.2.14-MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with Sequel Pro then I guess. If you first run the `prepare` and `execute` rows together it will work and show some output, at least it did for me, and then run the `deallocate` separately. I also tried from the command line and it worked fine there too.

Comment: Thank you @joakim-danielson
I will have a look!

Comment: That’s it! It made me go nuts.
But it works as you described.